Understanding instantaneous rest frames in general relativity
In special relativity, to derive formulas for proper time and proper distance, one uses the concept of instantaneous rest frames.
In order to calculate proper time of a massive object moving in the flat spacetime where events are described by coordinates $(T,X,Y,Z)$, one can find an inertial frame where an object remains at rest. Such frame is called an instantaneous rest frame. Spacetime in this frame can be described by metric $ds^2=-c^2d\tau^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$ where $\tau$ is object's proper time and $x,y,z$ are coordinates in rest frame. Next, we equate this metric with the flat spacetime metric:
$$ds^2=-c^2d\tau^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2=-c^2dT^2+dX^2+dY^2+dZ^2$$
An object in its instantaneous rest frame is at rest, so $dx=dy=dz=0$. We get this formula for proper time
$$\Delta\tau=\frac1c\int\sqrt{c^2dT^2-dX^2-dY^2-dZ^2}$$
Similarly, given two spacelike-separated events $a$ and $b$, one can find an instantaneous rest frame which an inertial frame where $a$ and $b$ are simultaneous. We equate the metric of the instantaneous rest frame with metric with the flat spacetime metric:
$$ds^2=-c^2d\tau^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2=-c^2dT^2+dX^2+dY^2+dZ^2$$
In the instantaneous rest frame, $d\tau=0$. The formula for proper distance between $a$ and $b$ is
$$L=\int_a^b\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}=\int_a^b\sqrt{-c^2dT^2+dX^2+dY^2+dZ^2}$$
Now I want to understand how to generalize the above derivations of proper time and proper distance to a curved spacetime described by metric $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$. Why in general relativity proper time $\tau$ is defined as $d\tau=\sqrt{-ds^2}/c$ and proper distance $\sigma$ is defined as $d\sigma=ds$?
I read an answer by @Qmechanic in a related question and I am struggling to understand what is going on in point 3 in their answer. In particular, how the temporal coordinate reparametrization works.
I think in general relativity instantaneous rest frames are now called proper frames. The linked page says that proper frames can either be inertial or not inertial. I am not sure how proper frames can be used to calculate proper time and proper distance.
After reading a bit about Riemann normal coordinates suggested by @naturallyInconsistent, I think that in a curved spacetime, the metric for a spacetime experienced by an observer in a timelike geodesic is approximately flat with some negligible higher order terms. The metric for a spacetime experienced by an observer who is undergoing hyperbolic motion with constant proper acceleration is approximately Rindler with some negligible higher order terms. The metric for a spacetime experienced by an observer who is in uniform circular motion approximately looks like the one here (6e) with some negligible higher order terms. I am not sure if this sounds correct though.
For example, for an observer in some fixed Schwarzschild coordinate $(R,\Theta,\Phi)$ in Schwarzschild spacetime described by metric
$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)c^2dt^2+\left(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$$
their spacetime can be described by a Rindler metric
$$ds^2=-\left(\frac{ax}{c^2}\right)^2c^2d\tau^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$
for some constant $a>0$. Here $\tau$ is proper time of the observer.
To calculate proper time of the observer, one sets $x=c^2/a$ (this is the default position for a Rindler observer) and $dx=dy=dz=0$ and the above Rindler metric becomes $ds^2=-c^2d\tau^2$ and it can be equated to Schwarzschild metric. To calculate proper distance, one sets $d\tau=0$ to get $d\sigma^2\equiv ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$ and equate $d\sigma^2$ to Schwarzschild metric.

The concept still works, but its range of validity is tiny. You cannot flatten the metric to the SR one. The best that you can do to make it almost the SR one, is to use Riemann normal coördinates. Even then, the metric is flat at the point of consideration, but continues to have the Riemann curvature term, so that only the infinitesimal neighbourhood is flattened.



In the instantaneous rest frame, dτ=0.  === Okay, but how is that different from the null surface, which is the 4-cone surface on which no time passes?



Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714606/in-what-coordinates-does-a-non-inertial-observer-make-measurements
